# latitud, longitud null con google maps Geocoder

Tags: javascript, google-maps

estoy haciendo que cuando ingrese la direccion me muestre la latitud y longitud pero me sale null o vacio, nose si me falta algo esto lo que llevo:

```
function initMap(){
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   center: centerMap,
   scrollwheel: false,
   zoom: zoom
 });

 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 $('#recoger').keyup(busquedaGoogle(geocoder));
}

function busquedaGoogle (geocoder) {
  return function (event) {
    var direccion = $(this).val();
    console.log(direccion);
    geocoder.geocode({'address': direccion}, function (results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
            console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
        }
        else{
            console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

resultado de la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código está fallando por otra razón. Supongo que es por el error de google ads, el cual impide que otra parte del código se ejecute total o parcialmente.

Hice un snippet con tu código (adaptado para la ocasión) que sí funciona.

**Sin embargo**, el problema que estás intentando resolver ya está resuelto. Google provee un widget para autocompletar direcciones, y éste reacciona al evento `place_changed` para que sepas cuando un usuario eligió una dirección.

De la manera como lo tienes hecho ahora, aunque funciona, vas a toparte con muchos errores por exceder la cuota de requests, visto que haces uno por cada tecla.

Te dejo el ejemplo con tu autocompletador y el de google.

```js
var centerMap={lat:0,lng:-77  },
    zoom=7;
    
function initMap(){
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   center: centerMap,
   scrollwheel: false,
   zoom: zoom
 });

 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 $('#recoger').keyup(busquedaGoogle(geocoder));
 
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($('#autocompletar')[0]);
  
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete,'place_changed',function() {
      var place=autocomplete.getPlace();
      console.log(place.geometry);
  });
}

function busquedaGoogle (geocoder) {
  return function (event) {
    var direccion = $(this).val();
    console.log(direccion);
    geocoder.geocode({'address': direccion}, function (results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
            console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
        }
        else{
            console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
  }
}


jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  initMap();

});
```

```css
#map {
width:100%;
height:90vh;
}
input {
width:40%;
margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&ext=.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="recoger" placeholder="input normal"/>
<input type="text" id="autocompletar" placeholder="autocomplete" />
<div id="map"></div>
```